# How to restrict APK not to Uninstall from "Android Devices"

Tags: android

I have developed Android Application and even I installed into the Devices. But how to prevent the application/apk not to uninstall by the others/user of the Device.

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 2):

***You CAN'T***.

*Until your application is a part of Framework, user of your application can uninstall the app and this is right of user.*

Although you can track the uninstallation of app by implementing [Device Admin API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: do you have any example for using Device Admin API. because Documentation is not very clear.Thanks.