# How do I prevent my application to being uninstalled on Android

Tags: android

I just need a parent filter so child cannot uninstall my application until parent gives permissions (like a password). It is possible ?

It is possible to prevent application from uninstalling ?

Below is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="de.impressive.artworx.tutorials.installedapps"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ListInstalledApps"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is a OS just like windows, linux and Mac. The OS has features that it allows/disallows its applications from using. You will need to probably write a native app on jail broken phones to get that kind of control on the OS.

Comment: im develop aplication for android tablet 4.1 jellybean

Comment: That is very interesting. The answer is still valid.

Comment: give me any example please

Comment: Google for "native android app development" also look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html also look at the link given above by @Pankaj Kumar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161358/how-to-restrict-apk-not-to-uninstall-from-android-devices

Comment: you can use GCM for device administration to prevent uninstallation of appication.

Comment: how do i add my application in notification bar so is notify every specific time to open my app

Comment: Google for "android notifications sample". And please ask a different question for a different problem. Please keep SO useful and clean. Thanks